# Render twig-template with dynamically placed HTML in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an action and a Twig-template.

Via `render()` it is possible to place a text for a Twig-tag `{{ tagname }}`.

But this text is escaped. Now I would like to place (not-escaped) HTML-code.

How is that done in Symfony2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Escaping is handled by Twig.

`{{ var }}` leads to escaped output.

`{{ var|raw }}` leads to raw/not-escaped output.

[raw is a filter](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#raw).